# Unable to Count the documents using spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, couchbase, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to use couchbase as the streaming source for spark structured streaming using spark connector.

```
val records = spark.readStream
.format(“com.couchbase.spark.sql”).schema(schema)
.load()
```

And I have this query

```
records
.groupBy(“type”)
.count()
.writeStream
.outputMode(“complete”)
.format(“console”)
.start()
.awaitTermination()
```

For this query I am not getting the correct output . My query output table is like this

```sh
Batch: 0
20/04/14 14:28:00 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 10.538654 ms
20/04/14 14:28:00 INFO WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source writer org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWriter@17fe0ec7 committed.
±-------±----+
|type | count|
±-------±----+
±-------±----+
```

However if I use the couchbase to fetch the documents as non streaming. Like

```
val cdr = spark.read.couchbase(EqualTo(“type”, “cdr”))
cdr.count()
```

Schema is correctly inferred for this non streaming operation and used the same schema for the structured streaming as well.

```
INFO N1QLRelation: Inferred schema is StructType(StructField(META_ID,StringType,true), StructField(_class,StringType,true), StructField(accountId,StringType,true),
```

gives the correct output. (count= 28).

Please let me know why this is not working with structured streaming.

Comment: I am not familiar with the couchbase connector, but maybe the default behavior is to look up for only new records? when you submit the stream you are trying adding new records to the couchbase or the records is already exists?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are streaming only what has changed from now onward and not the past events.
If you would like to stream everything "from the beginning" you need to specify that.

Example is shown in this blog post: https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spark-connector-2-0-0-released/

basically in your stream, you need to specify the following line

```
  .couchbaseStream(from = FromBeginning, to = ToInfinity)
```

Comment: I am using structured streaming. These are not available in that